# what is synonym for stored procedure??how to create synonym for stored proc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

If we consider stored procedure,How to pass local parameters and what is synonym for stored proc?

Comment: what is synonym mean?how to declare it with stored proc?

Comment: Please consult a SQL server tutorial or reference.

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx) website:

A synonym is a database object that serves the following purposes:

- Provides an alternative name for another database object, referred to
  as the base object, that can exist on a local or remote server.
- Provides a layer of abstraction that protects a client application
  from changes made to the name or location of the base object.

Synonyms can be created for the following types of objects:

- Assembly (CLR) Stored Procedure
- Assembly (CLR) Table-valued Function
- Assembly (CLR) Scalar Function
- Assembly Aggregate (CLR) Aggregate Functions
- Replication-filter-procedure
- Extended Stored Procedure
- SQL Scalar Function
- SQL Table-valued Function
- SQL Inline-table-valued Function
- SQL Stored Procedure
- View
- Table1 (User-defined)

Also you can create, drop or reference to a `Synonym` in a dynamic query. So you can put your [`CREATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) statement in a dynamic query and run it within your stored procedure.